# How to install .cer files on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, ssl, certificates

I need to install 3 security patches to access to internet. So I have downloaded the 3 patches, the 3 files are .cer type and i don't know how to install these files on Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: What is that? an openvpn connection?

Comment: I don't know ...

Comment: Can you provide full names of the files?

Comment: **_External_Certificate1.cer two other files are like this one

Answer (score 0):

1.Install openvpn:

```
$ sudo apt install openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

2.From Network indicator, click on Edit coonnections…

3.Click Add.

4.Choose OpenVPN and click Create…

5.Name it, choose gateway and give it the 3 certificate files.

6.Save it

7.Connect to it via VPN Connections submenu of the Network indicator

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But i have to change the format of these files ?

Comment: @F.Trust It is hard to say it without seeing the file. can you provide the structure of the file here?